# Can Microsoft account deploys an app to Windows phone 8.1 more than 3 devices for testing?

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-phone-8.1

I am new in Windows phone development application. I built an app package and use Application Deployment Tool deployed it to devices for testing. But a microsoft account only allows to deploy 3 devices in maximum. I tried The Chinese tool *aiyingyong_pc* to jaibreak the Windows phone but it not work. Are there any ways to deploy to many devices or any tools can jailbreak the Windows phone?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, except for Samsung devices, there is no jailbreak available for Windows Phone 8 (only for Windows Phone 7).

According to Microsoft, you can increase the device limit if you open a support ticket: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/matthiasshapiro/archive/2012/12/14/how-to-register-more-than-3-windows-phones-for-development.aspx
Honestly, I've never tried and the article is more than two years old, so I don't know if it's still true.

Otherwise, the only workaround left is publishing the app as a beta. Though not as convenient, you'll be able to install it on as many devices as you wish.

Comment: Thank you! But, the article in your link unusable!